# How to implement bots with netty

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, nio, netty

I've been working for a few months with netty now and I have a big question to make.

I'm trying to make an MMO game and I want to have Non Player Characters (NPCs) able to move around the game, react to real user interaction ( and be visible to other users as well, in real time).

What would be the best approach to do this?

I was thinking that I could create a "fake user" but I have no idea how to connect it to the socket server i'm using.

BTW: I'm using TCP connections to the server, from iPhone devices as clients.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to start a background thread on the server itself and handle everything related with NPCs there. It is a simple approach, and a lot easier than settings up a new client.

Comment: How do you recommend to implement that? I'm not sure I get the entire idea without a bit of code. I appreciate your quick anwser!